# AngularJS dynamically ng-model name from parameter

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, directive, angular-ngmodel

**Edit**

How to set for this `<input ng-model="this['newPlayer']['personal_info']['first_name']">`
the `['newPlayer']['personal_info']['first_name']` dynamically from variable?

Something like this: `<input ng-model="this[variable]">`

Comment: didn't understand what do you mean by 'hardcoded'

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: so you don't need this to be in scope of custom component anymore, do you?

Comment: I need - but I know how I can send the name of the model I need to the child directive/component. I just don't know how to apply it in the html... I can to `console.log($attrs.whatEverISent)` and it will be results just okay. But how to send the `whatEverISent` to the ng-model directive in the actual input tag?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to get it from the attributes just add this to your directive `require: 'ngModel'`
like this

```js
app.directive("textInput", () => {
  return {
    templateUrl: "/text-input.html",
    require: 'ngModel'
    scope: true,
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModel) {
      angular.element($element).append($scope[$attrs.myModel]);
    }
  }
});
```

and you have your different `ngModel` for each textInput instance in link function

Comment: No.. this is not the problem - What to write in the HTML of the directive?

Comment: I got the data via `$attrs` and via the `required` key anyway - but how to assign the value to the ng-model?

Comment: check this article on using `ngModel` in your custom components: https://www.codelord.net/2017/07/28/youre-not-using-ng-model-enough/